# UE 4 - How to setup Server Profiles via webapi with Steam integration

Tags: rest, unreal-engine4, steam, unreal-blueprint

Im working on a Unreal Engine 4 project with steam subsystem and advances sessions plugin.

I would like to store the player info (level, skilltree, etc.) on my server.

I've seen many videos how i can handle webapi calls with blueprint to achive this.
But in every scenario ive found, the api is publicly available without login.

How can i login to my api via steam subsystem to ensure players cannot manipulate others player data or get thyere private information?

Is there a way for doing this in blueprint or do i have to use C++ to achtive this?